Door issue - should it be re-installed or use shim?
I had a brand new door installed about 5 months ago. It was always a little tight on the right side but now I have to lift the door a bit to lock it because the locks do not align. There is about 1/16" between the door and the frame on the right side.
I had a handy man come over and say that it was installed wrong. I called the company that did the door and they said it probably just needs a shim on the hing from the door shifting.
Is the shim a hack? Does this mean the door was installed improperly or is it normal to use a shim for a issue like this?


If "the door was always a little tight on the latch side", then it was installed wrong. If it has shifted (without the house shifting), then that also indicates a wrong installation or an inferior door. The original installer wants to come back and try to fix it, I would let them try.
They are making the face saving claim that the door must have shifted so they don't have to admit that they screwed it up. I would let them use this excuse if they just fix the door. They will likely have to remove and reinstall the door.

Shims are used at installation time to adjust the door frame to be plumb, square, and level.  The rough opening should be slightly bigger than the door frame, so the door frame has a loose fit in the rough opening.
The hinge screws might be loose/too small to hold the door, especially at the top.
A simple cheap fix is to use longer screws to tighten the hinges to the frame and the door.
You should have the door frame(3/4 inch), maybe thin shims, a jack stud(1.5 inch) and a king stud(1.5 inch) before any danger of hitting electrics/plumbing with a screw.
